# A question on Hamming distance

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $X$ be the set of all ordered triples of zeros and ones. Show that $X$ consists of **eight** elements and a metric $d$ on $X$ is defined by $$d(x, y) = \text{number of places where}~~ x~~ \text{and}~~ y ~~\text{have different  entries}$$

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

More generally, $\mathbb R^n$ is a metric space with the metric $d(x,y)=\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k-y_k|$. The triangle inequality easily follows from the triangle inequality for real numbers.

Restricting the above to the set $\{0,1\}^n\subset \mathbb R^n$ yields the space described in the problem.

The fact that the cardinality of $\{0,1\}^n$ is $2^n$ can be proved by induction: $\{0,1\}^n $ is the disjoint union of $\{0\}\times \{0,1\}^{n-1} $ and $\{1\}\times \{0,1\}^{n-1} $.

Comment: Hello sır can you explain more ?